# Slowcheetah app.config pass parameters to transform file

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, teamcity, slowcheetah

I have following transform file `app.Release.config` to transform my `app.config` using SlowCheetah. How do I pass the `BUILD_NUMBER` from `TeamCity` so that the transform file replaces a particular xml elements value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MyApp.Data.Model" publicKeyToken="866d4a0fa0599fe0" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect name="MyApp.Data.Model.BR" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-$(BUILD_NUMBER)" newVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </dependentAssembly>      
</assemblyBinding>
```

If I hard code the value then SlowCheetah does the transformation. But, I don't know how to pass in the `build_number` as a argument so that for each build I can replace the correct version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to pass parameters to slowcheetah transform files. I'm using a XmlPoke Task to modify the contents of app.config.

My answer for this can be found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25929802/949702)